# Why python skips elif statement

Tags: python, pandas

What I am trying to do is to let user input a set of values separated with spaces, read them, compare correctly with the dataframe and print text accordingly.
What may look like a simple task turned out in many hours of struggling.
What is strange:

1. else statement by itself is working properly, but its formatting differs from if statement
2. if statement formatting seems correct, but it doesn't work right.
   It always prints that 'All numbers are in dataframe' no matter what I type in.
3. elif statement is never recognized

I converted input str to list, which can be seen in the code example.
So, this is clearly not related to data type.
Any help will be very appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd

in1 = input("Choose certain numbers separated with spaces:")
in1 = in1.strip()

result = pd.DataFrame([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5], columns=['Numbers'])

uniq_numbers = list(result.Numbers.unique())

print(type(in1))
in1 = in1.split()
for i in range(len(in1)):
    in1[i] = int(in1[i])
print(type(in1))

if all(result[(result['Numbers'].isin([in1]))]):
    print('All numbers', in1, ' are in dataframe:', uniq_numbers)
elif not all(result['Numbers'].isin(in1)):
    print('No numbers', in1, ' were found in dataframe!', uniq_numbers)
else:
    print('Some of the numbers entered:', in1, 'are NOT in dataframe, be aware. \n',
     'Valid number/s:',
     set(in1).intersection(result),
     '\n Number/s that were NOT found in dataframe:',
     (set(in1) - set(result))
          )
```

Input: 6 7
Output:
All numbers are in dataframe
['6', ' ', '7']

Comment: Wasn't this question already closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @JRiggles They' ve changed the code, it's almost right.

Comment: `isin([in1])` should be `isin(in1)`. `in1` is already a list, you don't need to put it inside `[]`.

Comment: @Barmar I tried this too, doesn't help(

Comment: @JRiggles it was, I modified the question.
I never find the right answer for this unfortunately

Comment: I think you may have your conditions backwards. You want to test if all the `in1` numbers are in the dataframe, not if all the dataframe numbers are in `in1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major problems. You are not testing whether all numbers in the list are in the data frame, but rather if all numbers in the data frame are in the list. The problem with the `if` statement is that as the argument of the `all` function you are not using an iterable of `bool`s, but rather an object, data frame in this case.

To test whether all numbers in the list are in the data frame you can use `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

result = pd.DataFrame([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5], columns=['Numbers'])
numbers = [1, 3, 5]
mask = np.isin(numbers, result['Numbers'].unique())

if np.all(mask):
    print('All numbers present')
elif not np.any(mask):
    print('None numbers present')
else:
    print('Some numbers present')
```

To know which numbers from the list are present in the data frame, you can use the `mask` variable. Number `numbers[i]` is present in the data frame if `mask[i]` is `True`. If you transform numbers to `numpy` array, you can simply get all present numbers as

```py
numbers_present = np.array(numbers)[mask]
```

This is possible, because you can index `numpy` arrays using `bool`s.

Comment: Thank you, it works!
I spent so many time on this(
"You are not testing whether all numbers in the list are in the data frame, but rather if all numbers in the data frame are in the list" - it's true, I thought about this as well, while reading my "if" statement which goes literally as "if values in dataframe is in input" but I looked at a tons of examples and everywhere I saw exactly this way to compare a set with dataframe, so I thought "okay, maybe I don't understand much".
So frustrating that sometimes it is so hard to find a correct example of such a simple thing.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:
I think it will solve your problem:

```py
import pandas as pd

in1 = input("Choose certain numbers separated with spaces:")
in1 = in1.strip()

result = pd.DataFrame([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5], columns=['Numbers'])

uniq_numbers = list(result.Numbers.unique())

print(type(in1))
in1 = in1.split()
for i in range(len(in1)):
    in1[i] = int(in1[i])
print(type(in1))

in1_set = set(in1)
uniq_numbers_set = set(uniq_numbers)

if in1_set.issubset(uniq_numbers_set):
    print('All numbers', in1, ' are in dataframe:', uniq_numbers)
elif not in1_set.intersection(uniq_numbers_set):
    print('No numbers', in1, ' were found in dataframe!', uniq_numbers)
else:
    print('Some of the numbers entered:', in1, 'are NOT in dataframe, be aware. \n',
     'Valid number/s:',
     in1_set.intersection(uniq_numbers_set),
     '\n Number/s that were NOT found in dataframe:',
     in1_set - uniq_numbers_set
          )
```

In this corrected code, we convert `in1` and `uniq_numbers` to sets and use the `issubset` method to check if all numbers in `in1` are in the DataFrame. We also use the `intersection` method to check if any numbers in `in1` are in the DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately it seems that the "if" statement is always skipping.
If I input "1 4" digits (both presented in dataframe) the output is:
Some of the numbers entered: [1, 4] are NOT in dataframe, be aware. 
 Valid number/s: {1, 4} 
 Number/s that were NOT found in dataframe: set()

Comment: I changed the code; Please try again.